# d3js to plot vector data from json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm pretty new to D3 and json files so apologies if this is a somewhat elementary question. I have a dataset with four fields organized in columns, say:

```
Name Time Value
X t1 v1
X t2 v2
X t3 v3
Y t1 V1
Y t2 V2
Z t1 V1
Z t2 V2
Z t3 V3
Z t4 V4
```

As you notice, these data are basically time series of V for various names all in the same file. I want to transfer this to a json file to be read by d3 and plotted. It strikes me that the most efficient way would be if I can somehow organize it in a way where I can have members in the json file such that

Option 1 -

```
{name:'X',time:[t1 t2...],value:[V1 V2...]} for each name
```

Option 2 - Another alternative would be:

```
{name:'X',time:'t1',value:'v1'},{name:'X',time:'t2',value:'v2'} and so on for each name
```

I'm aware that option 2 is possible but it seems a little inefficient with repeatedly storing the name. Is option 1 possible to store in json and plot using d3?

I don't seem to be able to find any examples for option 2 and how I could go about plotting data like that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: With d3 it is best to have one object per element in the visualization - you can carry this principle into nested/grouped visual components, I'd suggest a format such as : `[{name: "X", values: [{time:'t1',values:'v1'}, {... }}, {name: "Y", values: [ {},{}...]} ]`. Your existing options 1 and 2 will be more difficult to work with than necessary for most visualization types or cause unforeseen complications.

Comment: Thanks! It is a lot of extra text in the json file, making it bulkier, but the downstream advantages perhaps compensate for that. Follow up Q - If i were using a pandas dataframe to process this data into json, would df.to_json be a good way to do this?